# Reversing bits and converting binary to decimal in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal, byte, bit

I'm building a function that, given an integer, reverses all 32 of its bits (including sign bit), converts that into a new integer, and returns it. I've almost finished it but I've run into two problems:

**Part 1:**
If I give it test(15); then

buffer = 11110000000000000000000000000000, which is indeed 15 with all the bits reversed.

but if I give it test(-15); then

buffer = 10001111111111111111111111111111, which is NOT right, it should be 10001000000000000000000000000001 (the 1 at the end is the sign bit). So for negative values, building my buffer string is going awry. *Should I just change it to a positive integer, reverse the bits, and change the bit at the end to 1*? **Or is there some easier way of building this string?**

**Part 2:**

"answer", the integer I'm returning that is supposed to represent these numbers, is never accurate. If I give it test(1500) answer = 185, when it should be 1000341504. **What's the best way to turn a 32-bit binary number into an integer?**

my code:

```
int test(int var){
   printf("reversing %d:\n", var);
   char buffer[32];
   int i = 0;
   int power = sizeof(var) * 8;
   int answer = 0;

   while(power > 0){

      //check the lowest bit and put a 0 or 1 into the array
      if((var & 1) == 1){
         buffer[i] = '1';
         i++;
      }

      else{
         buffer[i] = '0';
         i++;
      }
      //shift to the next bit
      var>>= 1;
      power--;
   }

   i++;
   buffer[i] = '\0';

   printf("\nbuffer =  %s", buffer);

   //loop through the array in reverse, building the number
   while(i > 0){
      if(buffer[i] == '0'){

         i--;
      }
      else{

         answer += (2 ^ (32 - i));  //here is where I try to add up answer
         i--;
      }
   }
   printf("\nanswer = %d \n\n\n\n", answer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: -15 in 32-bit binary is 111111111111111111111111111111110001, which reversed in 100011111111111111111111111111111111; your code *is* correct (at least in this respect).

Comment: wait a second, are you trying to do *2 to the power of (32-i)* with `2 ^ (32 - i)`? `^` is the XOR-operator.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Representing negative numbers in that way is *two’s complement*, not simply binary.

Comment: Here are some [bit-twiddling tricks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious) that may be of interest to you.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: There is no "simply binary" way to represent negative numbers.

Comment: @ScottHunter: That is correct. And that is why it is false to state that “-15 in 32-bit binary is 111111111111111111111111111111110001.” Well, actually, there are two reasons. One is that 11111111111111111111111111110001 as binary is 4,294,697,281, not −15. The other is that 111111111111111111111111111111110001 is 36 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: If you pass -15 into a C function, it will be represented by a bit pattern -- THAT'S the binary representation OP is working with, and the bit pattern I posted (well, minus the "bonus" 1's).

Comment: @ScottHunter: The C standard permits three representations for negative values. Two’s complement is only one of them. So standard C does not guarantee this bit pattern will be used for −15. The reason the OP sees the pattern they do is not because −15 is that pattern in binary. It is because it is that pattern in two’s complement **and** because their C implementation uses two’s complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incorrect part of your conversion is:

```
answer += (2 ^ (32 - i))
```

`2 ^ (32 - i))` is `2 XOR (32 - i)`, because `^` is the XOR-operator.

I'd do the conversion like this:

```
unsigned int answer = 0, pow=1;
for(int i = sizeof(buffer) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    int bit = buffer[i] - '0';

    answer += bit * pow;

    pow *= 2;
}
```

By doing it backwards (from 31 to 0), you don't have to use `pow` or create a
function that does *2 to the power of i*. That would give you the integer value
of your binary interpretation, always positive. If you want to the integer value
of a 2-complement binary:

```
int answer = 0;
unsigned int pow=1;
for(int i = sizeof(buffer) - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    int bit = buffer[i] - '0';

    answer += bit * pow;

    pow *= 2;
}

if(buffer[0] == '1')
    answer |= 0x80000000; // setting last bit
```

Or the more general solution (doesn't care if `answer` is signed or unsigned)

```
int answer = 0; // or unsigned int answer = 0;
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
for(int i = len - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    if(buffer[i] == '1')
        answer |= 1 << len - 1 - i;
}
```

**edit**

I also found an error on your conversion to string:

```
char buffer[32];
...
i++;
buffer[i] = '\0';
```

The buffer hold 32 `char`s, one for each bit. There is no room left for the
0-terminating byte there, also with `i++` you are overflowing the buffer, `i`
would be 33, so you are overflowing by 2.

If you are not going to treat `buffer` as a string (no `strcpy`, no `strcmp`,
no `printf`), then you don't have to store the terminating `'\0'`. Remove the
`buffer[i] = '\0';` and that's it.

However you do print it as a string, so you would have to declare `buffer` as

```
char buffer[33];
```

and remove the `i++` before `buffer[i] = '\0';`.

In that case, you would need to change the `for` loops as well, to

```
for(i = sizeof(buffer) - 2; i >= 0; --i)
```

and

```
for(i = sizeof(buffer) - 2; i > 0; --i)
```

or `strlen(buffer) - 1` instead of `sizeof(buffer) - 2` (in case you do the
convertion on another function and you pass the pointer to `buffer`.

Comment: Wow, that looks perfect! Thank you so much, and thanks for the explanation of the XOR. I had heard of that but didn't know what it meant until now.

Comment: @Lazarus I've made an update of my answer, I found an error on my code which I fixed and I also found another error on your code, I address that error on my answer.